# Canon 80D DC Coupler to automatically turn DSLR back on after power outage

Tags: dslr, power

I am setting up a very long term time lapse and a big concern is that if the power goes out I need my DSLR to automatically turn back on. This is because I will have limited access to the camera when running.

I am a DR-E6 DC coupler with a LP-E6N dummy battery powering at the appropriate voltage (8V).

Issue is when I test the functionality, instead of the camera turning on automatically it instead flashes an empty battery signal for about 10 seconds on the mini screen and then remains off.

My findings:

1. If I engage the camera's battery door micro switch it powers on properly (or open and close the battery compartment door).
2. If I switch the on and off button back on it powers properly too.

Is there any way to override this power option? Is there any way to jump start it with software? I tried with EOS utility software however the camera is not detected unless I do what I stated in items 1/2 above.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the [magic lantern](https://www.magiclantern.fm/) firmware can be of use?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way to remotely turn on a Canon EOS camera.

However, this reads like an [*XY Problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/348605).

Your most practical solution would be to use an uninterruptible power supply to prevent the camera from ever powering down. Even a modest UPS could power an 80D and the transformer for the DR-E6 coupler for a rather long time if there is a power failure.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your post.
Unfortunately I am already using a UPS to power a computer as well and with the space constraints I have I will need way more juice than I can get.

Answer (score 0):

There are DC couplers that are powered by a USB charger, so if you replace the charger by an external USB power bank that can be kept charging while feeding its output, the power bank will continue powering the camera during power cuts.